# Approximating a random variable by random variables with continuous densities

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable, and suppose there is an $s > 0$ for which $\mathbb E[X^s] < \infty$. I want to construct a family $(Y_\sigma)_{\sigma > 0}$ of nonnegative random variables with the following properties:

1. $X$ and $Y_\sigma$ are independent for all $\sigma > 0$;
2. $XY_\sigma$ has a continuous density for all $\sigma > 0$;
3. $Y_\sigma$ converges in distribution to $1$ as $\sigma \searrow 0$.

My reference text (Achim Klenke's *Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course*, 3rd ed., Exercise 15.1.5ii) recommends taking $Y_\sigma$ to be independent of $X$ and uniformly distributed on $[1-\sigma, \sigma]$. This doesn't satisfy 2, though: if $X = 1$ almost surely, or if $X$ is supported on a Cantor set, then $XY_\sigma$ doesn't have a continuous density.

Is a construction like this possible?

**EDIT:** I tried doing this where $Y_\sigma$ has a continuous density as well, e.g., $Y_\sigma$ has a "tent density":
$$
f_\sigma(y) = \begin{cases}
\sigma^{-2}(y+\sigma-1) & \textrm{if } 1-\sigma \leq y \leq 1\\
-\sigma^{-2}(y-\sigma-1) & \textrm{if } 1 < y \leq 1+\sigma \\
0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
But in that case, we get:
$$
\mathbb P\left[ XY_\sigma \leq x \right] = \int \mathbb P\left[XY_\sigma \leq x \: | \: Y_\sigma = y\right] \, \mathbb P_{Y_\sigma}[dy] = \int \mathbb P\left[ X \leq \frac x y \right] f_{\sigma}(y) \, dy
$$
and without knowing anything about the distribution of $X$, I'm not sure how we can conclude that $x \mapsto \mathbb P\left[ XY_\sigma \leq x \right]$ is differentiable. Alternatively, we could write
$$
\mathbb P\left[XY_\sigma \leq y\right] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb P\left[Y_\sigma \leq \frac{y}{x}\right] \, \mathbb P_X[dx] 
$$
but even if $y \mapsto \mathbb P[Y_\sigma \leq y/x]$ is differentiable, that derivative may not be integrable with respect to $x$ and the measure $\mathbb P_X$, so differentiation under the integral may not be allowed.

Comment: Change $Y_\sigma$ a bit so it will have continuous density.

Comment: @mihaild I considered that, specifically where the density of $Y_\sigma$ forms a "tent" above $1$ of growing height as $\sigma \to 0$:
$$
f_\sigma(y) = \begin{cases} \sigma^{-2}(y+\sigma-1) & \textrm{if } 1-\sigma \leq y < 1 \\ -\sigma^{-2} (y-\sigma-1) & \textrm{if } 1 \leq y \leq 1 + \sigma \\
0 & \textrm{else} \end{cases}
$$
In this case, we get $\mathbb P[XY_\sigma \leq x] = \int \mathbb P[X \leq x/y] f_\sigma(y) \, dy$. Without knowing anything about the distribution of $X$, I'm not sure why we should believe this is differentiable with respect to $x$.

Comment: Try to move division under density, and differentiate under integral sign.

Comment: What do you mean by moving "division under density"? And differentiating under the integral sign requires knowing something about the distribution of $X$ in order for it to be a valid operation (namely that the distribution is itself differentiable).

Comment: Another possibility is to write $$\mathbb P[XY_\sigma \leq x] = \int_{[0,\infty)} \mathbb P\left[Y_\sigma \leq \frac y x \right] \, \mathbb P_X[dx].$$ In principle, we could differentiate under this integral to get the density, but only if $\frac{d}{dy} \mathbb P[Y_\sigma \leq y/x] = f_\sigma(y/x)/x$ is integrable with respect to the measure $\mathbb P_X$.

Comment: Note that, to even define $XY_\sigma$ in a guaranteed way as a measurable function out of a probability space, you need to create some kind of canonical product space, probably $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ is sufficient as you don't care about $Y_\sigma$ being independent of $Y_\sigma'$

Comment: @FShrike I don't follow. Products of measurable maps are measurable in general (as can be proven using a product space, for example).

Comment: As in, if you have a super generic probability space $\Omega$ and $X$ is given as $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$, can you always guarantee you also have a function $Y_\sigma:\Omega\to\Bbb R$? Such that $\omega\mapsto X(\omega)Y_\sigma(\omega)$ has the properties you want? (I mention it because it's a technical quibble, and it annoys me that it is rarely explicitly talked about by textbooks) It's common practice to re-jig $X$ so it's defined on $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ (say) where you can easily control a definition of a desired function (often the projection map to $\Bbb R$)

Comment: Eg if $\Omega$ only has two elements, you definitely can't build a uniformly distributed $Y_\sigma$ on it...

Comment: @FShrike you're correct, of course, but I'm not really concerned about that; if needed, we can extend our original probability space via a product as you've described.

Comment: Ya, I just object to the imprecise problem statement ; )